# Dynamic Programming algorithm shortest path between two

Tags: dynamic-programming

There's an algorithm currently driving me crazy.

I've seen quite a few variations of it, so I'll just try to explain the easiest one I can think about.

Let's say I have a project P:

Project P is made up of 4 sub projects.

I can solve each of those 4 in two separate ways, and each of those modes has a specific cost and a specific time requirement:

For example (making it up):

```
P:               1    +    2      +    3     +    4  + .... n

A(T/C)          Ta1/Ca1     Ta2/Ca2  etc      

B(T/C)          Tb1/Cb1 etc
```

Basically I have to find the combination that of those four modes which has the lowest cost. And that's kind of easy, the problem is: the combination has to be lower than specific given time.

In order to find the lowest combination I can easily write something like:

```
for i = 1 to n
    aa[i] = min(aa[i-1],ba[i-1]) + value(a[i])
    bb[i] = min(bb[i-1],ab[i-1]) + value(b[i])
    ba[i] = min(bb[i-1],ab[i-1]) + value(b[i])
    ab[i] = min(aa[i-1],ba[i-1]) + value(a[i])
```

Now something like is really easy and returns the correct value every time, the lowest at the last circle is gonna be the correct one.

Problem is: if min returns modality that takes the last time, in the end I'll have the fastest procedure no matter the cost.

If if min returns the lowest cost, I'll have the cheapest project no matter the amount of time taken to realize it.

However I need to take both into consideration: I can do it easily with a recursive function with O(2^n) but I can't seem to find a solution with dynamic programming.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If there are really just four projects, you should go with the exponential-time solution. There are only 16 different cases, and the code will be short and easy to verify!

Anyway, the I'm pretty sure the problem you describe is the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is NP-hard. So, there will be no exact solution that's sub-exponential unless P=NP. However, depending on what "n" actually is (is it 4 in your case? or the values of the time and cost?) there may be a pseudo-polynomial time solution. The Wikipedia article contains descriptions of these.

Comment: I used four just to make an example, it could be a lot more i just wanted to make it easy.
On top of that, theres plenty of fairly similiar ones.
I've also taken in consideration the knapsack, the problem is: it could work but at the same time in the knapsack each item is compatible with eachother, in this one it's not the case. I can use both mod 1 and 2 that's why recursion works. Also I "have" to solve it with dynamic programming, else I wouldn't bother looking for a solution honestly :D